# option value turning undefined

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a code that switches the theme of my site from one theme to another using a select element. The code for the function was:

```
function changeTheme(theme) {
    sltr = document.getElementById('themepicker');
    theme = theme + '.css';
    document.getElementById('help').innerHTML = theme;
    sltr.setAttribute('href', theme);
}
```

The code for the select element is:

```
<select id="theme" onchange="changeTheme(this.options.value)">
    <option value="mainstyle" selected>Default/Grove Colors</option>
    <option value="maindark">Dark</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `value` of a `select` element is the selected option's value, just use `this.value`:

```
onchange="changeTheme(this.value)"
```

Comment: No problem @TylerSilberman, if my answer fixed your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the grey tick mark to the left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To get the selected value, you want `this.value` rather than `this.options.value`.

As in:

```
<select id="theme" onchange="changeTheme(this.value)">
```